# Why does the Monotone Convergence Theorem require increasing sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

The monotone convergence theorem in my text requires $f_n$ to be a non-negative, increasing, pointwise convergence sequence.

Why does $f_n$ have to be a decreasing sequence? Is there an example of when the sequence is decreasing it the theorem is not true?

Comment: If only $\int f_N\,d\mu < \infty$ for some $N$ and $f_n\downarrow f$ (pointwise a.e.), then $\int f_n\,d\mu\to\int f\,d\mu$ as $n\to\infty$ by dominated convergence.

Comment: Maybe look up a standard example where Fatou's Lemma has a strict inequality to see what can happen if a sequence of functions is not monotone.